# Last.FM API in Android Studio 404 error

Tags: android, android-studio, restful-authentication, last.fm, loopj

I'm attempting to use the last.fm API (http://www.last.fm/api/mobileauth) restful using Android Studio and the Loopj Android AsyncHttpClient plugin (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) but I keep getting a 404 error, but can't see why. Code below. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("username", "myusername");
params.put("password", "mypassword");
params.put("api_key", "myapikey");
params.put("api_sig", "myapisecret");

LastFMRestClient.post("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/", params,
    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            String msg = "Object *" + statusCode + "*" + responseBody;
            Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Failed: " + msg);
            // Outputs: Failed: Object *404*[B@17f1042c
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Finished");
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the method parameter and wasn't using https on the url!